# DynamoDB Map/Document is empty when scanned, but is not empty in the table

Tags: c#, database, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I have a DynamoDB Attribute saved as this:

Sensori.cs

```cs
[DynamoDBProperty]
public Document misurazioni;
```

When I query it using this method:

```cs
var sensor = await context.LoadAsync<Sensori>(id, tipo_misurazione);
return sensor;
```

The sensor is ok except the `misurazioni` Document is empty, with no values.
[Debug Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SaZrj.png)

Even though in the real database, it has values.

Comment: What does the awscli yield when making the equivalent query?

Comment: It works with aws cli: [image](https://i.imgur.com/NE2FIp5.png). @jarmod

Answer (score 0):

For some reason, the DynamoDB Map isn't correctly converted to a Document, so add this to your Sensori.cs file

```
    ...
    [DynamoDBProperty(Converter = typeof(MisurazioniConverter))]
    public Document misurazioni;
}

// Custom property converter for the Document objects
class MisurazioniConverter : IPropertyConverter
{
    public object FromEntry(DynamoDBEntry entry)
    {
        // Convert the DynamoDBEntry object to a Document object
        var document = entry as Document;
        return document;
    }

    public DynamoDBEntry ToEntry(object value)
    {
        // Convert the Document object to a DynamoDBEntry object
        var document = value as Document;
        return document;
    }
}
```